# Boolean simplification, 5 variables

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm currently learning for my maths exam, and in the part about boolean algebra I came across an exercise that I can't seem to solve. I probably only need the first few steps to get started.

$$ (xyz + uv)(x+\overline{y}+\overline{z}+uv) $$

Usually, if I get into trouble, I can fall back to a truth table or VK-diagram, but that's just too much work for 5 variables.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the terms in the two brackets. You get:
$$ xyz + 0 + 0 + xyzuv + xuv + \overline{y}uv + \overline{z}uv + uv$$
$$ xyz(1+uv) + uv(1+x+\overline{y}+\overline{z})$$
$$ xyz + uv $$

NOTE:

$1 + x = 1$

$1.x = x$

$x.x = x$

$x.\overline{x} = 0$

Comment: Wow, it really seems simple this way. Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's write it like this:
$$\begin{align}
(xyz + uv)((x+\bar y + \bar z) + uv)&\equiv((xyz)(x+\bar y + \bar z) + (xyz)(uv))+(uv(x + \bar y + \bar z) + uvuv) \\
&\equiv ((xyz)(x+\bar y + \bar z) + xyzuv)+(uv(x + \bar y + \bar z) + uv)\\
&\equiv ((xyz)(x+\bar y + \bar z) + xyzuv)+(uv) \\
&\equiv ((xyzx + xyz\bar y + xyz\bar z) + xyzuv)+(uv) \\
&\equiv ((xyz + 0 + 0) + xyzuv)+(uv) \\
&\equiv (xyz + xyzuv)+(uv) \\
&\equiv (xyz)+(uv) \\
\end{align}$$

From line 1 to line 2, we distributed.  From 2 to 3, we noted that $ab + a \equiv a$. From 3 to 4, we distributed again.  From 4 to 5, we noted that $a\bar a\equiv 0$ (contradiction), which we remove from 5 to 6.  6 to 7 we note $ab + a \equiv a$.

Comment: Is $ a\bar a\equiv c $ the same as $ a\overline{a} = 0 $ ? I've never seen the first notation, we use the second.

Comment: @SimonVerbeke In the class I took, we used $c$ to denote a contradiction, and $\tau$ to denote a tautology.  We also used the $a\land b$ and $a \lor b $ operators instead of $ab$ and $a+b$, respectively.  I'll edit my question to use the $0$ to denote contradiction.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Yours is a good solution too, but I find lsp's solution simpler. So I'm going to accept his as the answer.